# best practice for mounting filesystems

Tags: filesystems, mount

say I have two virtual disks (`dev/sda` and `dev/sdb`added to my ESX CentOS 7 VM). I create two partitions (`dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`). Then I create a physical volume for each and create a volume group named `storage-vg` and two logical volumes `data` and `application`. 
File system created as well: 
`mkfs.ext3 /dev/storage-vg/data`  `mkfs.ext3 /dev/storage-vg/application`

My question is where do I mount them now ? I mean if I mount to a directory that contains already data the data will be hidden so to say. What is the best practice ? Should I create two empty directories under `/` ?

It might be a silly question but for someone will almost only Windows experience it's hard to understand.

Comment: This seems to me to hover on the "opinion-based" guideline; you *can* mount them anywhere you want, and there are impacts to over-mounting existing directories, as you note.  Really, it boils down to "whereever you want"

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks Jeff. That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have exactly one place for every mount point aside from root `/`, you could use the standard `/mnt/my-mount-point`. And eventually symlink if necessary.

I do this for my home folder for example and find it very clean, but ultimately it is opinion-based.

#### Scenario

I am mounting `/dev/sda1` in `/mnt/downloads` but I'd like to access this folder from `~/downloads`. So I symlink it with `ln` utility:

```
ln -s /mnt/downloads $HOME/downloads
```

And now, doing

```
cd ~/downloads
```

Is equivalent to

```
cd /mnt/downloads
```

Comment: `And eventually symlink if necessary.` Symlink what exactly? Can you give please an example?

Comment: @yesOrMaybeWhatever I updated my answer to clarify :-)

Comment: I would discourage /mnt personally, as I (and others?!) have a habit of mounting temporary things at /mnt, which would cover up child mounts.